# How to auto play a YouTube video with a custom image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

I have an image, when you click on it it shows an embedded YouTube video.

http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/NW557/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#player").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#player").html('<iframe width="475" height="267" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/mHX_JjoTplQ?rel=0&&controls=2&showinfo=0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
  });
});
```

I want my video to play automatically after a person clicks on the image, but nothing happens even after I added the autoplay=1 parameter to the YouTube URL.

How can I make the video autoplay after the images gets clicked on?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/NW557/1/

Comment: Oops, my bad – I missed the ?autoplay=1, should have been &autoplay=1. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider reading up on how HTTP query parameters work. There were already three parameters defined, so you instead need to add `&autoplay=1` to the end.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#player").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#player").html('<iframe width="475" height="267" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/mHX_JjoTplQ?rel=0&&controls=2&showinfo=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to achieve that with Youtube videos, i think you should try to do that with the api. It's pretty simple to use and you have a better control on the video commands and events.